# openNTF Domino API causing large amounts of log files - StackOverflowError

Tags: xpages

I've been testing and using the openNTF Domino API (ODA) very heavily these past few days, and i am starting to notice large amounts of log files being generated. (ODA version M4.5) Yesterday, I found more than 10,000 of them.  Today, there are a few hundred.  It seems to be written once a day and about the same time time of day (roughly 14:00 to 15:00). All print outs of the stacktrace are the same.  Here is an excerpt from the log:

```
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM: java.lang.StackOverflowError
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at sun.nio.cs.SingleByteEncoder.encodeArrayLoop(SingleByteEncoder.java:70)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at sun.nio.cs.SingleByteEncoder.encodeLoop(SingleByteEncoder.java:146)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:555)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder$CharsetSE.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:405)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:159)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:122)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:500)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:643)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:780)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.logging.DefaultFileHandler.publish(DefaultFileHandler.java:134)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:1281)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:1244)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.utils.DominoUtils$4.run(DominoUtils.java:279)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:327)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.utils.DominoUtils.handleException(DominoUtils.java:273)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.iterators.DocumentIterator.getCollectionIds(DocumentIterator.java:79)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.iterators.DocumentIterator.<init>(DocumentIterator.java:53)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.impl.DocumentCollection.iterator(DocumentCollection.java:747)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.impl.NoteCollection.add(NoteCollection.java:159)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.impl.DocumentCollection.toLotusNoteCollection(DocumentCollection.java:83)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.iterators.DocumentIterator.getCollectionIds(DocumentIterator.java:70)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.iterators.DocumentIterator.<init>(DocumentIterator.java:53)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.impl.DocumentCollection.iterator(DocumentCollection.java:747)
14.10.2014 15:02:16   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.impl.NoteCollection.add(NoteCollection.java:159)
```

The last bit loop endlessly.  I was unable to find a corresponding entry in the org.openntf*.log file.

**EDIT***
After going through a few hundred documents, I did see this variation from the normal loop.  Whether or not it is relevant, I cannot say:

```
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM: Error trying to format output for error handling. Resorting to standard stack trace...nullnull
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM: java.lang.StackOverflowErrorjava.lang.StackOverflowErrorjava.lang.StackOverflowError
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at sun.nio.cs.SingleByteEncoder.encodeArrayLoop(SingleByteEncoder.java:70)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at sun.nio.cs.SingleByteEncoder.encodeLoop(SingleByteEncoder.java:146)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:555)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder$CharsetSE.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:405)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:159)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:122)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:500)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:643)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at java.io.PrintStream.append(PrintStream.java:1039)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at java.io.PrintStream.append(PrintStream.java:51)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at java.lang.StackTraceElement.appendTo(StackTraceElement.java:180)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at java.lang.Throwable.appendTo(Throwable.java:305)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:332)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:212)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:163)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.logging.DefaultConsoleHandler.publish(DefaultConsoleHandler.java:104)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:1281)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:1244)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.utils.DominoUtils$4.run(DominoUtils.java:279)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:327)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.utils.DominoUtils.handleException(DominoUtils.java:273)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.iterators.DocumentIterator.getCollectionIds(DocumentIterator.java:79)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.iterators.DocumentIterator.<init>(DocumentIterator.java:53)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.impl.DocumentCollection.iterator(DocumentCollection.java:747)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.impl.NoteCollection.add(NoteCollection.java:159)
14.10.2014 15:10:29   HTTP JVM:     at org.openntf.domino.impl.DocumentCollection.toLotusNoteCollection(DocumentCollection.java:83)
```

1. Is this a known issue? If so, how can I correct it?
2. If I cannot correct it quickly, can I at least turn off the print out into the server log?
3. Is this indeed an error with the API as it seems from the stacktrace, or could it be that I am using it incorrectly?

Comment: Is there a "caused by" line in the stack trace?

Comment: No.  Granted I did not go through the hundreds of documents, but the first three documents and last three documents do not contain a  caused by clause.  The rest are a loop of the same data.  No testers reported any sort of usability error, so I am not even certain if a specific function was called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a problem fixed in a subsequent release which I think was related to iterators.

In M4.5, if adding a DocumentCollection to a NoteCollection it will call the iterator on the DocumentCollection at line 159 https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.domino/blob/M4.5/org.openntf.domino/src/org/openntf/domino/impl/NoteCollection.java.

However, the DocumentCollection iterator is instantiated by calling getCollectionIDs, which adds the DocumentCollection to a new NoteCollection at line 83 https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.domino/blob/M4.5/org.openntf.domino/src/org/openntf/domino/impl/DocumentCollection.java.

This is the cause of the stack trace, but in the Release Candidate subsequent to M4.5, this is fixed. The corresponding method, starting on line 180, now just uses the core NoteCollection.add method https://github.com/OpenNTF/org.openntf.domino/blob/master/org.openntf.domino/src/org/openntf/domino/impl/NoteCollection.java

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have upgraded and will see if this fixes the problem.  I will monitor the server logs in the next few days.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, update to the RC2.1 to fix this - had the same issue when using RC2.0

Comment: yup, that is the version that corrects it.  Actually, this version makes sense for many more reasons such as .getFirstDocumentByKey() rather than .getDocumentByKey being deprecated without a substitute. The only reason why I did not go straight to this version was because it was "only" a "candidate" for release.